# Concat ASCII character in a textbox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, textbox, ascii

I would like ton display a "ruler" on a textbox.

I'm thinking about displaying the u031D character in a textbox...

So i do this :

```
        for (int nI = 0; nI <= TxtBox_ApercuFichier.Text.Length; nI++)
        {
            TxtBox_Regle.Text = TxtBox_Regle.Text.Trim() + "\u031D";
        }
```

With this code, it only display on character. I i use a standard charactere, for a exemple, the letter "A", the concat is ok.

Do you know why ?

Thanks a lot :)

Regards,

Comment: [Using "\u2534"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box-drawing_character#Unicode) might get you somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\u031D` is not ASCII. That is a unicode code point. Apparently the [characters between 0300 and 036F are combining characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character), meaning they are only intended to modify other characters.

You can get them to show by providing characters on either side, but the result is probably still not what you are looking for:

```
textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.Trim() + " " + "\u031d" + " ";
̝//yeilds : ̝ ̝ ̝ ̝ ̝
```

> Update

I think this will get you started building a ruler on your form without trying to use text characters. Implement the paint event on your form:

```
private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    int counter = 0;
    Point start = new Point(10, 50);
    Point end = new Point(510, 50);

    using (Pen thickpen = new Pen(Color.Black, 2f))
    using (Pen thinpen = new Pen(Color.Black, 1f))
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(thinpen, start, end);

        for (int i = 0; i < 501; i += 5)
        {
            if (counter % 5 == 0)
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawLine(thickpen, start.X + i, start.Y, start.X + i, start.Y - 5);
            }
            else
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawLine(thinpen, start.X + i, start.Y, start.X + i, start.Y - 3);
            }

            counter++;
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Basic Ruler]

Comment: I really need to concat ONLY this character...it's in order to "design" a ruler  :( And i cannot use an image . I want to now this type or ruler ( -> http://www.noelshack.com/2016-16-1461410824-excel.png)

Comment: @WalterFabioSimoni, that ruler is not created with text. There are other unicode characters you can try but you will never achieve the look you want that way. You can [draw lines on forms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cyh3c8h8(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Wow it's very great man :) Now i have to display dynamically number on this ruler all the 10 for example :) Very great man :)

Comment: Crowcoder, i tried the code and it's great, by the way i don't know if it's really the method using by Microsoft on Microsoft Excel ( when you try to open a non XLS/XLSX file). Because this draw is statical, and i a draw this ruler on top at my textbox, if i scroll my textbox, the draw don't scroll, and it's normal. I would like to do the same than in Microsoft Excel :(

Comment: @WalterFabioSimoni, it can be done, but it would be complex to keep in sync with scrolling. [Maybe try this](https://sourceforge.net/projects/netrulercontrol/)

Comment: OK, i will find another simply method so :) Thanks